# Fixed Header - Stops Animating When Scrolling Down, continues when stop scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a fixed menu for my website.

Everything is working quite fine, the problem is;

When I scroll down, as soon as the fixed menu starts animating, if I scroll down faster it stops, and when I stop scrolling down, the animation continues until it gets fixed.

The JS is below;

```
function init() {
        window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
            var topbar = $("#topbar"),
                header = $("#header-main"),
                hdr_img = $("#header-main .inner img"),
                hdr_inner = $("#header-main .inner"),
                search = $("#search"),
                cart = $("#cart");
            $(window).width() > 1200 && ($(this).scrollTop() > 235 ? (header.addClass("sabit"), hdr_inner.addClass("sabit"), search.addClass("sabit"), cart.addClass("sabit"), hdr_img.addClass("sabit"), topbar.addClass("sabit"), header.stop().animate({
                top: "-44px",
                opacity: 1
            }, 800), topbar.stop().animate({
                top: "-44px",
                opacity: 0
            }, 900)) : $(this).scrollTop() < 1 && (header.stop().animate({
                top: "0px",
                opacity: 1
            }, 800), topbar.stop().animate({
                top: "0",
                opacity: 1
            }, 1300), header.removeClass("sabit"), hdr_inner.removeClass("sabit"), search.removeClass("sabit"), cart.removeClass("sabit"), hdr_img.removeClass("sabit"), topbar.removeClass("sabit")))
        })
    }
    window.onload = init();
```

Also CSS codes are below;

```
#topbar {
  color: #7BBD42;
  background: #2e3a47;
  background-image: url("//images....com./sprites/kullanicimenupat.png");
  padding: 5px 0;
  min-height: 30px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #7bbd42;
  border-width: 3px;
}
#topbar.sabit {
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
z-index: 99;
top: 0;
}

#header-main {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  min-height: 107px;
  color: #8c8c8c;
}
#header-main.sabit{
position : fixed;
width: 100%;
z-index: 1010;
padding-top: 35px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #AFC999;
min-height: 100px;
min-height: 99px;
background: rgba(255,255,255,1);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(245,245,245,1) 47%, rgba(237,237,237,1) 93%, rgba(237,237,237,1) 99%);
background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(47%, rgba(245,245,245,1)), color-stop(93%, rgba(237,237,237,1)), color-stop(99%, rgba(237,237,237,1)));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(245,245,245,1) 47%, rgba(237,237,237,1) 93%, rgba(237,237,237,1) 99%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(245,245,245,1) 47%, rgba(237,237,237,1) 93%, rgba(237,237,237,1) 99%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(245,245,245,1) 47%, rgba(237,237,237,1) 93%, rgba(237,237,237,1) 99%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(245,245,245,1) 47%, rgba(237,237,237,1) 93%, rgba(237,237,237,1) 99%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#ededed', GradientType=0 );
}

#header-main .inner {
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 25px;
  padding: 0;

#header-main .logo img {
  /*background-color: #7bbd42;*/
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in 0s;
}
#header-main .inner.sabit{
margin-bottom: -15px;
margin-top: 18px;
}
#header-main .inner.sabit img {
  max-width: 75%;
  margin-top: -4px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
}
```

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but why not just use the "position:fixed" property?

Comment: Why you name variables in a soooooo weird fashion?

Comment: @GiacomoPaita Okay, i updated variables for readability. Jeremy, that didn't work out

Comment: the issue does not occurs to me: all seems to go the right way.

Comment: @GiacomoPaita I uploaded a video to indicate the problem

Answer (score 1):

Use a `setTimeout` inside the scroll event:

```
var timerX = -1;
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
    clearTimeout(timerX);
    timnetToChangVp  = setTimeout(function() {
        init();
    }, 200);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because of [.stop()](https://api.jquery.com/stop/).

> Stop the currently-running animation on the matched elements.

Every time when you scrolling it stopping animation and starting again. Remove `.stop()` you can see effect then.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I don't use stop, after a few scrolls animations are getting messed up and doesn't load stable. I tried it before and I also tried it now after your answer but still no luck (atleast with my methods :))

Comment: As in the jQuery documentation: ".stop( [clearQueue ] [, jumpToEnd ] )", try pass ".stop(true, false)"

Comment: @GiacomoPaita Thanks Giacomo, when I cancel the animation if I scroll continiously it works (ends animation immediately) but what I am trying is I need animation to continue even if I scroll.